# Retornar List<T> por Json a JS desde c# con clase que contiene otra clase

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

Tengo una clase `Localidad` que contiene un atributo de la clase `Provincia`, al querer hacer los combos anidados por Ajax con Jquery me da un:

> error 500 - Internal server error-.

Si yo saco el atributo `Provincia`, anda perfecto. ¿Cómo puedo solucionar esto?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

    namespace javaScript.Models
    {
        public class Localidad
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Descripcion { get; set; }

            [Display(Name ="Provincia")]
            public int IdProvincia { get; set; }

            public Provincia Provincia
            {
                get { return new Provincia(this.IdProvincia); }
                set { }
            }

            public void set_Provincia(int idProvincia)
            {
                this.Provincia = new Provincia(1);
            }
        }
    }

namespace javaScript.Models
{
    public class Provincia
    {
        // public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Descripcion { get; set; }
        public string Gobernador { get; set; }
        public List<Localidad> Localidades { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Método en el Controller para retornar la lista:

```
public ActionResult GetSecondValues(string IdProvincia)
{
    IEnumerable<Localidad> localidadList = null;
    var db = new Contexto();

   var id = Int32.Parse(IdProvincia);
    if (id > 0)
    {
        //se carga la lista de Localidades       
        localidadList = db.Localidades.Where(x => x.IdProvincia == id).ToList();
    }
    var retorno = Json(localidadList);
    return retorno;
}
```

Método Ajax en la vista:

```js
 <script type = "text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#IdProvincia").change(function () {
            var selectedItem = $(this).val();
            var ddlStates = $("#IdLocalidad");
            var statesProgress = $("#states-loading-progress");
            statesProgress.show();
            $.ajax({
                cache: false,
                type: "POST",
                url: "@(Url.Action(" GetSecondValues "))",
                data: {
                    "IdProvincia": selectedItem
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    ddlStates.html('');
                    $.each(data, function (id, option) {
                        ddlStates.append($('<option></option>').val(option.Id).html(option.Descripcion));
                    });
                    statesProgress.hide();
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert('Failed to retrieve states.');
                    statesProgress.hide();
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema surge por una Recursividad entre la clase **Provincias** que contiene un **List de Localidades** y la clase **Localidades** que Contiene un atributo del tipo **Provincia**
Lo raro que el error salta en el método ajax y no en Visual Studio, lo que me dificulto encontrar el error, porque ajax solo me decía Error 500 Internal server error y no tengo mucha experiencia en JS. 
Quitando cualquiera de los dos atributos (la lista de localidades en provincia, o la provincia en localidades) El código funciona correctamente.

```
 public class Localidad
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Descripcion { get; set; }

            [Display(Name ="Provincia")]
            public int IdProvincia { get; set; }

            **public Provincia Provincia
            {
                get { return new Provincia(this.IdProvincia); }
                set { }
            }**

            public void set_Provincia(int idProvincia)
            {
                this.Provincia = new Provincia(1);
            }
        }

  public class Provincia
    {
        // public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Descripcion { get; set; }
        public string Gobernador { get; set; }
        **public List<Localidad> Localidades { get; set; }**
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Según entiendo, el error que estás obteniendo sería **Cannot implicitly convert type X to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable< Localidad >'**.

Esto sería porque el tipo que devuelve **db.Localidades** no puede convertirse directamente a una lista de **Localidad**.

Podrías probar con lo siguiente:

```
localidadList = db.Localidades.Where(x => x.IdProvincia == id).Select(
    l => new Localidad
    {
        Id = l.Id,
        Descripcion = l.Descripcion,
        IdProvincia = l.IdProvincia
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: No, el error me lo da en la vista en el success. Si le quito el atributo Provincia anda bien

Comment: Hola, el error que te sale 500 - Internal server error es en el servidor, has hecho depuración a este método para poder ver en qué linea se encuentra el error?

Comment: Si, el método en el controller se ejecuta bien, el error sale cuando ajax recibe el listado

Comment: Según entiendo, en el método $.ajax, después de que haces la búsqueda del listado, entra al método error, lo que mandaría el alert('Failed to retrieve states.'), correcto?

Comment: Exacto, entra en el error: de la funcion ajax

Comment: Vale, eso significa que el error si está en el servidor, por eso te preguntaba si habías depurado el método, lo otro que podrías hacer es intentar hacer que el atributo sea ignorado al momento de serializar **localidadList**, porque según veo no lo estás utilizando en ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Un problema que veo es que estás usando [`Int32.Parse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.parse(v=vs.110).aspx) para convertir la cadena `IdProvincia`, pero si este llegara a ser nulo te enviará un [`ArgumentNullException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentnullexception(v=vs.110).aspx), esto genera una excepción y por ende cobra sentido el error 500, entonces lo ideal sería usar el método [`Convert.ToInt32`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Convert.ToInt32.aspx).

Lo ideal, será cambiar tu código del Controller por lo siguiente:

```
public ActionResult GetSecondValues(int IdProvincia)
{
    IEnumerable<Localidad> localidadList = db.Localidades.Where(x => x.IdProvincia == IdProvincia).ToList();
    return Json(localidadList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

---

Pero, que viendo el resultado lo usas para llenar una lista desplegable, recomendaría generar el HTML desde el Controller:

```
public ActionResult GetSecondValues(int IdProvincia)
{
    IEnumerable<Localidad> localidadList = db.Localidades.Where(x => x.IdProvincia == IdProvincia).ToList();

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var localidad in localidadList)
    {
        sb.Append("<option value='" + localidad.Id + "'>" + localidad.Descripcion + "</option>");
    }

    ViewBag.Localidades = sb.ToString();

    return View();
}
```

Por último, en la llamada Ajax solamente faltaría *renderear* ese HTML en el control deseado:

```
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    type: "POST",
    url: "@(Url.Action(" GetSecondValues "))",
    data: {
        "IdProvincia": selectedItem
    },
    success: function (data) {
        ddlStates.html('');
        ddlStates.append(@Html.Raw(ViewBag.Localidades));
        statesProgress.hide();
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert('Failed to retrieve states.');
        statesProgress.hide();
    }
});
```